# CSS3 Box Shadow not working in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a design for a small page with css3 features being used.

For some reason I can't get -webkit-box-shadow working on this page (and just this page).
I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

http://kin.remuria.net/flipfinder/test/

Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong with this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your box shadow a color

`box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px #000000;`

EDIT:

If you want to support older versions of browsers that don't support the more standard `box-shadow` property then using both proprietary prefixes `-moz` `-webkit` in combination with the `box-shadow` property is fine.

Comment: Besides the fact that I AM using box-shadow, this worked. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I guess my point was why use both proprietary prefixes (-moz) AND the standard CSS3 box-shadow, but i guess i can see where this will be helpful with older versions of chrome/safari and mozilla. I will edit the post.